# How to Copy a Timestamp Datatype

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a table with a `TIMESTAMP` column:

```
create  table dbo.EX_EMPLOYEE (
    NAME_X            varchar(10) null,
    RECORD_TIME_STAMP timestamp   null
    )
```

when I copy the rows from one table to another, using either:

```
SELECT * INTO EX_EMPLOYEE_T 
    FROM EX_EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE 1=0
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE_T
    SELECT * 
        FROM EX_EMPLOYEE
```

I get this warning:

> Warning: A non-null value cannot be inserted into a `TIMESTAMP` column by the user. The database timestamp value has been inserted into the `TIMESTAMP` field instead.

The `TIMESTAMP` column in the target table is replaced with the current database timestamp.

**My question**
How to copy rows with a `TIMESTAMP` column, while preserving the `TIMESTAMP` value from the source table ?

(Is there a setting similar to `SET IDENTITY ON/OFF`)

**My scenario**
I have 2 tables, one for "live" data and the other for "backup", so I need to copy the rows with the `TIMESTAMP` intact. I need it intact in order to detect if there has been a change to the "live" row.

Comment: Unable to test it now, but I think bcp is able to copy into timestamp columns

Comment: @PerformanceDBA the creation table is explained in my question. SELECT * INTO EX_EMPLOYEE_T FROM EX_EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=0
.. the answer provided from markp is good but its causing WARNING if i dont scpecify column in insert INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE_T
SELECT * FROM EX_EMPLOYEE

Comment: 1) So specify the column.  2) @markp explicitly states that you cannot use SELECT-INTO; that you must use INSERT-SELECT; that the columns must be specified.  3) SELECT-INTO is never a good thing anyway, not acceptable in production systems.  View it as a development-only convenience.  4) You don't want to "disable the timestamp", you want to copy it intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sybase (now SAP) replication server (SRS) can replicate timestamp values between Sybase/SAP ASE tables, ie, the SRS maintuser can insert explicit values into a column of type `timestamp`.

How is this possible?  There are a few requirements:

- the user performing the insert (to the `timestamp` column) must have the `replication_role` role (and it has to be active)
- you need to issue the `set timestamp_insert on` command (NOTE: this will generate an error if your user doesn't have `replication_role`)
- you need to explicitly list the target table's columns in the insert statement

Setup:

```
exec sp_displaylogin
go
...
Configured Authorization:
        ...
        replication_role (default ON)      <<<=== verify role assigned and active
        ...

create table EX_EMPLOYEE
(NAME_X                 varchar(10)     NULL
,RECORD_TIME_STAMP      timestamp       NULL
)
go

insert into EX_EMPLOYEE (NAME_X) values ('Larry')
insert into EX_EMPLOYEE (NAME_X) values ('Mo')
insert into EX_EMPLOYEE (NAME_X) values ('Curly')
go

select * from EX_EMPLOYEE
go

 NAME_X     RECORD_TIME_STAMP
 ---------- ------------------
 Larry      0x00000000ec4304fa
 Mo         0x00000000ec4304fd
 Curly      0x00000000ec430501

select * into EX_EMPLOYEE_T FROM EX_EMPLOYEE where 1=2
go
```

Now for some insert tests ...

```
-- haven't issued the 'set timestamp_insert on' commmand, yet

insert into EX_EMPLOYEE_T
select * from EX_EMPLOYEE
go

Warning: A non-null value cannot be inserted into a TIMESTAMP column by the user. The database timestamp value has been inserted into the TIMESTAMP field instead.

-- received the *WARNING*, ie, rows are inserted but they receive new timestamp values

select * from EX_EMPLOYEE_T
go

 NAME_X     RECORD_TIME_STAMP
 ---------- ------------------
 Larry      0x00000000ec430548       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Mo         0x00000000ec43054a       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Curly      0x00000000ec43054c       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE

-- enable direct insert of timestamp values

set timestamp_insert on
go

truncate table EX_EMPLOYEE_T
go

-- w/out explicitly listing target columns ...

insert into EX_EMPLOYEE_T
select * from EX_EMPLOYEE
go

-- no warning message is generated, insert succeeds, but new timestamp values are generated

select * from EX_EMPLOYEE_T
go

 NAME_X     RECORD_TIME_STAMP
 ---------- ------------------
 Larry      0x00000000ec430555       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Mo         0x00000000ec430557       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Curly      0x00000000ec430559       <<<=== different from what's in EX_EMPLOYEE

truncate table EX_EMPLOYEE_T
go

-- this time we'll explicitly list the target table's columns ...

insert into EX_EMPLOYEE_T (NAME_X, RECORD_TIME_STAMP)
select * from EX_EMPLOYEE
go

-- and now we see the timestamp values copied from the source

select * from EX_EMPLOYEE_T
go

 NAME_X     RECORD_TIME_STAMP
 ---------- ------------------
 Larry      0x00000000ec4304fa       <<<=== same as what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Mo         0x00000000ec4304fd       <<<=== same as what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
 Curly      0x00000000ec430501       <<<=== same as what's in EX_EMPLOYEE
```

Above was tested on a ASE 15.7 SP138 dataserver.

Comment: I am getting error like this 
insert into EX_EMPLOYEE_T select * from EX_EMPLOYEE but if add the columns it get fixed do you knw why ?

Comment: I have clarified & cleaned up the Question.  You may wish to reduce the answer; remove the now superfluous references & examples; etc.